# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 - iOS build fails - Missing anywhere-plugins-ios.zip does not exist

Tags: ios, maximo, maximo-anywhere

When running ./build.sh clean all to build iOS Anywhere app - the build process fails with this detail errors:

```
/Users/jess/IBM/Anywhere/MaximoAnywhere/build.xml:127: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/jess/IBM/Anywhere/MaximoAnywhere/anywhere-platform-installer.xml:641: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/jess/IBM/Anywhere/MaximoAnywhere/anywhere-platform-installer.xml:568: src '/Users/jess/IBM/Anywhere/MaximoAnywhere/build/managed/plugins/iphone/anywhere-plugins-ios.zip' doesn't exist.
```

Is this due to missing step during Anywhere 7.6 installation in Mac OS?

Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  This file should have been extracted during the "build install-platform" target on Mac OS as part of the Install process.  If you check the logs here, you can probably figure out the root cause of the error

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258203

However, you should be able to manually fix the environment by running this command.

```
/Users/jess/IBM/Anywhere/MaximoAnywhere/build.sh install-platform all
```

Comment: This is fixed the issue. Thanks Scott.